# How can the searchform.php know if it's used on a registered sidebar id 'sidebar-1' or 'sidebar-2'?

Tags: php, functions, widgets, search, sidebar

For example I have:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar 1', 'mytheme' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    ...
) );
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Sidebar 2', 'mytheme' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-2',
    ...
) );
```

And I have my own */searchform.php* for customizing search engine, and my Sidebar 1 have a Search widget.. Now, how can that search engine's PHP code know where registered sidebar id is it?

Answer (score 0):

This should never be a path you try to follow. Widgets should always behave the same way wherever they are placed. If you need two types of searches then you need two different widgets.

If this is a specific per client theme you can style it differently based on sidebar, but even in such a type of project anything which is more than CSS changes will be a surprising thing for the client when he will try to make changes to the theme, and to the developer that will come after you.

Comment: thx for helping, but what I'm trying to do is to track the search engine's sidebar id and track the sidebar button's customization and apply that customization into the search engine's *"Search"* button, every sidebar have their own button customization.

Comment: In that case, you have to have an explicit parameter in the widget. Again, if you have a different widget you can pass it in an hidden input.

Comment: P.S. the sidebar's customization is a class string of many choices and want to be applied to the sidebar's search engine's button. Can you give me an example or link to an info how to have an explicit parameter in the Search widget and how to pass it in a hidden input?